# iOS Restore from backup retain CoreData application data?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, itunes

If someone does a full backup of their iPhone, to backup apps etc, and then on lets say a new iphone they do a restore from backup. Obviously this will copy the apps to the new iphone, but does it restore the app data / core data as well? etc

What exactly gets restored?
- CoreData?
- NSUserDefaults?
- Keychain?

If someone could clear this up for me, that would be great.

Many Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your appdata (Keychain,NSUserDefaults, CoreData, and /Documents) does get restored.

Comment: Hi PRNDL, thank you for your response. Do you have any online literature/dev docs I can read to confirm this?

Comment: In the article you posted, I found the following: When you restore a device from a backup of a **different** device (e.g., when you buy a new iPhone and transfer all your data), keychain data gets transferred **only** if the backup was encrypted (password protected). If you restore to the **same** device, the limitation does not apply: Keychain gets restored regardless of backup encryption.